# how to change an image based on an if statements requirements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
var mpegArray = ["1.m4a", "2.m4a", "3.m4a", "4.m4a", "5.m4a", "6.m4a", "7.m4a", "8.m4a", "9.m4a", "10.m4a"];
var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * mpegArray.length);

function btnPlay_onClick() {
    var player = document.getElementById('sound');
    player.src = mpegArray[choice];
    player.play();
    player.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        if (player.ended) {
            mpeg();
        }
    }, true);
}

function btnN1_onClick() {
    var Audio1 = document.getElementById("audio1");
    Audio1.play();
    if (choice == 0) {
        document.getElementById("btnN1").src = "1GR.gif";
        ans.innerText = CORRECT;
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("btnN1").src = "1RD.gif";
        ans.innerText = INCORRECT;
}
```

hiya the code here is meant to get number tiles to change colour based on if the requirements of the if statements are met. here the if statement is asking if button 1 is pressed after the audio file 1.m4a is played change the colour of he tile to green if not change it to red

Comment: You are missing one }. That's why it doesn't execute.

Comment: ooo i did thanks for letting me know. It didnt manage to sort the issue though

Comment: You need your `{ }` for your else statement. If you have 1 line after the `if` or `else` then you don't need brackets. Otherwise you need `else{ ..... }`

Comment: ive added the { after the else but that hasn't changed anything

Answer (score 0):

You might be better served changing the css with a background colour/image instead of the src attribute.

```
document.getElementById("btnN1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("btnN1").style.backgroundImage = "url('1GR.gif')";
```

**EDIT:** GiaFil7 is right. You're missing a closing } after the second if statement which might be causing your issue.

Comment: the issue is with the if statement its not executing correctly the images change on click but it doesnt meet the reqirements of the if statemnet

Comment: "Gia" isn't my name. If that's ok can you edit your answer to contain my whole nickname?

Comment: of course. I couldn't see the whole nickname when I was editing :)